# Node 'Flatten/Merge' Array of Objects Containing Arrays and Display with forEach in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatten

Apologies for any repeats here, please point me in the direction of a solution if one exists.

Any other time, I seem able to display array data in ejs no problem, but this new flatten function has me stumped.

I have a nested array:

```
var array = 
[{
  page: {
    results: [{
        id: "1234",
        type: "page",
        title: "Deprecated Spec",
        children: {
          page: {
            results: [{
                id: "5678",
                type: "page",
                title: "Deprecated | Cash Spec"
              },
              {
                id: "9101",
                type: "page",
                title: "Deprecated | Ledger Spec",
              }
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        id: "1121",
        type: "page",
        title: "Work Spec"
      }
    ]
  }
}];
```

And I have a flatten function:

```
function flatten(arr) {
  let flattened = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      flattened = flattened.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
    } else {
      flattened.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return flattened;
}
```

I set a const and console.log:

```
const newArr = (flatten(array))

console.log(newArr);
```

In the terminal I receive: **[ { page: { results: [Array] } } ]**

For what it's worth, I've also tried flattening this nested array with these methods, and both return the same results.

```
const newArr2 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array);

const newArr3 = array.flat();
```

Hmm ok, I figure I can forEach and display the data on the .ejs page, which is set as:

```
<% newArr.forEach(function (newArr){ %> 
        <%= newArr.title %>
    <% }) %>
```

But this shows nothing.

I have the res.render functioning properly as I am able to send and display other arrays/data sets.

If I try to "get into the array" with something like this: **newArr[0].page.results**, or any other variances, they don't work.

What am I missing to see my flattened array (using the recursive function) in both the console.log and on my ejs page?

**UPDATED:**
Per comments below, here is my desired output for the arrays and objects seen in var array:

```
[{
  page: {
    results: [
       {
        id: "1234",
        type: "page",
        title: "Deprecated Spec"
       },
       {
        id: "5678",
        type: "page",
        title: "Deprecated | Cash Spec"
       },
       {
        id: "9101",
        type: "page",
        title: "Deprecated | Ledger Spec"
        },
        {
        id: "1121",
        type: "page",
        title: "Work Spec"
        }
    ]
  }
}];
```

Here is a pic of my current console.log
[image: can see array/objects and console log]

Many Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `flatten`? You `array` is not an array of arrays. So your `flatten` does basically nothing.

Comment: Thanks @some-user My understanding (which is new-to-node) is that I have an array inside of an array since **title: Deprecated Spec** has two children (title: "Deprecated | Cash Spec" & title: "Deprecated | Ledger Spec") that appear to be inside an array. Is this not correct?

Comment: `flatten` will only affect arrays that contain arrays as their element. Your data structure is more complicated. The elements of your array are objects which then contain arrays...

Comment: Ah thank you, I've updated my Topic title but will leave everything else for context. So how do I go about bringing the children titles/properties up to the same level as the parents? I'm not sure what to call this method if it's not 'flatten'. Is there documentation you can point toward or help with my code?

Comment: You need to adapt the implementation of `flatten`. Currently it does nothing. But apparently you want it to do something. If you can give the desired output of the function, people might be able to suggest how the implementation could look like.

Comment: updated desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adapt your code to flatten the array like this to achieve the desired output:

```js
const array = [
  {
    page: {
      results: [
        {
          id: '1234',
          type: 'page',
          title: 'Deprecated Spec',
          children: {
            page: {
              results: [
                {
                  id: '5678',
                  type: 'page',
                  title: 'Deprecated | Cash Spec',
                },
                {
                  id: '9101',
                  type: 'page',
                  title: 'Deprecated | Ledger Spec',
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          id: '1121',
          type: 'page',
          title: 'Work Spec',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]

function flatten(arr) {
  const flattened = []
  for (const { children, ...element } of arr) {
    flattened.push(element)
    if (children) {
      flattened.push(...flatten(children.page.results))
    }
  }
  return flattened
}

const flat = [{ page: { results: flatten(array[0].page.results) } }]

console.log(flat)
console.log(flat[0].page.results)


// [
//   {
//     "page": {
//       "results": [
//         {
//           "id": "1234",
//           "type": "page",
//           "title": "Deprecated Spec"
//         },
//         {
//           "id": "5678",
//           "type": "page",
//           "title": "Deprecated | Cash Spec"
//         },
//         {
//           "id": "9101",
//           "type": "page",
//           "title": "Deprecated | Ledger Spec"
//         },
//         {
//           "id": "1121",
//           "type": "page",
//           "title": "Work Spec"
//         }
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @some-user, thank you for your patience with me, I've copied your code verbatim, however, instead of the full console.log of flat that you show, all I see in console.log is **[ { page: { results: [Array] } } ]**

Comment: That's just the way the output is limited. Try `console.log(flat[0].page.results)`.
Your welcome, you can select the answer as the right answer if it works for you.

Comment: That works, I apologize for the follow up, this seems to be a moving target as I learn, a couple questions if you don't mind: 1) can you give a 'name' to what you're doing here? Are you flattening an array or object with arrays of objects? 2) can you please point to any documentation?